# How do I handle a callback in java

Tags: java, servlets, asynchronous, glassfish

I have a servlet that request a geolocation from another server using an http get. The response is received via a callback from the other server and ends up in another servlet. Ideally I would like to return a map on the first servlet and make this asynchronous mechanism synchronous. All I can come up with at the moment is to poll a shared hashmap till the value is there, it seems like a bit of an ugly hack. Any ideas how I can implement this more elegantly?

Comment: If you're using Servlet 3, you can check how you can do [asynchronous processing](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2009/jw-02-servlet3.html).

Comment: The asynchronous processing part in terms of servlet 3 is not the issue. The issue is that the request is generated in one servlet and the response in another and needs to be fed into the original servlet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the most basic level, using a condition variable is more efficient than a non-blocking loop.

```
// global, shared lock.
final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
final Condition locationReceived  = lock.newCondition(); 

// first servlet:
//
lock.lock();
try {
    requestLocation();
    if (!locationReceived.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
        // location was not received in the timeout.
    } else {
        // read location from shared object.
    }
} finally {
    lock.unlock();
}


// servlet that receives geolocation
//
lock.lock();
try {
    // set location in shared object.
    locationReceived.signal();
} finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```

Comment: That looks good unless I get 10 or 20 requests at the same time and then have to allocate the answers to the requests. At the moment I use a hashmap for that. The lock would prevent most likely imho break this asynchronous communication. I'm no expert when it comes to this sort of thing. Please tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: Some things you can do  1: try to put all the work in one servlet.   2: create a map as you have, that manages the requests.   I'd make  a class to handle this, giving clients a ticket (ID) with which they can ask for the result at a later point.  However, you'll want to put an expiry on those tickets and results, (which need-not require a new thread, but could.  See guava's MapMaker class).

Comment: Thanks for the MapMaker class hint. I was considering implementing something similar.